# How to deploy GWT Project containing GWT modules without entry points with Eclipse GAE plugin?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I have a GWT Project containing some GWT modules that I would like to have NO entry point, functioning as libraries for other modules WITH entry points.

The GWT 'entry point' modules compile fine with the "GWT Compile Project" option in Eclipse if I choose not to compile the GWT 'library' modules with them. They also run fine.

When I choose to deploy my project to the Google App Engine with the "Deploy App Engine Project" option, all modules will get compiled and this process gets stuck on the 'library' modules, since they have no entry point defined.

Is there a way to get around this? I now 'fixed' it by adding a Dummy.java file to the libraries that implement EntryPoint and have an empty onModuleLoad in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell GWT which modules have an entry point.  Right-click on the icon for the project, choose Google > Web Toolkit Settings..., and remove your library module from the list of "Entry Point Modules."

This change is persistent and will affect all of your compiling actions, including deploying to GAE.  The options you choose from "GWT Compile Project" are transient and only last for one compile.

This should tell the "deploy app engine project" action to stop trying to compile your library modules.

Comment: The original poster was talking about the dialog the appears when you click "GWT Compile Project."  You can remove modules from that dialog, but the change is temporary - it only lasts for one compile.  Changes you make from Google | Web Toolkit Settings are persistent.

Comment: Wow, it was this simple. Can't believe I overlooked it, tnx!

Comment: Something about the setup is pretty confusing.  It took me a really long time to find it too - I kept having to ADD modules at each compile.